# How to use a temporary column in a WHERE statement when reading data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use a concatenated field in a where statement, but I am getting an error.
Original statement:

```
select id_number, problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3, concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) as Issue
from table_issues
where concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) like ('%Critical%')
```

What I try to achieve:

```
select id_number, problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3, concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) as **Issue**
from table_issues
where **Issue** like ('%Critical%')
```

or

```
declare @Issue as varchar(255)
select id_number, problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3, concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) as @Issue
from table_issues
where @Issue like ('%Critical%')
```

So that I do not repeat the concat in the where statement again.

Note that this is a semi-dummy, the actual condition is a complex where statement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just move your `concat()` into the `WHERE`

```
select id_number
     , problemlevel1
     , problemlevel2
     , problemlevel3
from table_issues
where concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) like '%Critical%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliases are not available in `WHERE` clauses at the same level at which they were defined.  One option would be to use a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CONCAT(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) AS Issue
    FROM table_issues
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE issue LIKE '%Critical%';
```

Comment: Using a CTE is a great idea, however I am getting an error:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: Hi Don, sorry, I was missing a parenthesis earlier, reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the subquery:

```
select * from
(select id_number, problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3,
concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3) as Issue
from table_issues)
where Issue like '%Critical%'
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me an error:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Can you please check again as error indicates that there is an issue with the syntax but I can not see any issue with syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @Issue as varchar(255)
select @issue = concat(problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3)
from table_issues

select id_number, problemlevel1, problemlevel2, problemlevel3, @Issue
from table_issues
where @Issue like ('%Critical%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to define a column:

```
select ti.id_number, ti.problemlevel1, ti.problemlevel2, ti.problemlevel3, v.issue
from table_issues ti cross apply
     (values (concat(ti.problemlevel1, ti.problemlevel2, ti.problemlevel3))
     ) v(issue)
where v.issue like '%Critical%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21d027a7eab02eb99ad4c542088dfc79) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunaltely I am getting an error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "ti.problemlevel1" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "ti.problemlevel2" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "ti.problemlevel3" could not be bound.
```

Comment: @DonCheiron . . . As I say in the text, use `cross apply`.  I just needed to follow my own instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just say:

```
WHERE (problemlevel1 LIKE '%Critical%' 
       OR 
       problemlevel2 LIKE '%Critical%'
       OR 
       problemlevel3 LIKE '%Critical%'
      )
```

Which should be simple enough...